# How to search branch_count and repository list by name in single network call of Github Api?

Tags: swift, api, rest, github, github-api

I am trying to use `Github Search Api` to show a list of repositories by name. My requirement is to show a list of all repositories matching name or description with string provided by user in search bar.
I was sucessfully able to do so by using this call `

> https://api.github.com/search/repositories?q=swiftui&page=1&per_page=10
> `
> But my problem is it does not returns branch count, which is an essential to show. How can I do this without making multiple network calls.

Comment: as you said, the api does not return the branch count, so you **must** do another network call to get that.
Presumably do another call to `branches_url`, then count the number of items received.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have tried some different methods using Rest API, but couldn't find any solution for branch count. So In the end Graphql was the solution for my problem.

```
let getReposQuery: String =
               """
               query getRepos($searchText: String!) {
                 search(query: $searchText type: REPOSITORY first: 10) {
                   nodes {
                     ... on Repository {
                       name,
                       description,
                       createdAt,
                        refs(first: 100, refPrefix:"refs/heads/") {
                         totalCount
                             nodes {
                               name,
                               id
                             }
                       }
                     }
                   }
                 }
               }
               """
```

With this query, you need to provide `searchText` as variable.